# How to prove that if the preimage of an open set is open the function is continuous?

Tags: general-topology

The definition I use for continuity is as follows:
$f:X\to Y$ (X and Y are metric spaces) is continous means that:
$\forall y\in X$ held constant,$\forall \varepsilon >0$ $\exists \delta$, s.t for all x satisfying $d_X(x,y)<\delta$: $d_Y(f(x),f(y))<\varepsilon$.

Let $V\subset Y$ be an open set.

I mananged to show that if f is continous then $f^-1(V)$ is an open set.  However I can't manange to prove the other way around, because $d_Y(f(x),f(y))$ can be smaller than epsilon, yet $d(x,y)$ can still be greater than delta. Can someone help me prove that if $f^-1(V)$ is an open set then f is continous?

Comment: Your definition of continuity is wrong. What you wrote is *uniform* continuity, which is a stronger property, hence no surprise you cannot prove it with the sole hypothesis that preimages of open sets are open.

Comment: The [answer to your previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4723156/386889)   advised you to look at Wikipedia for usual definitions of continuity and proof of their equivalence. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Continuous_functions_between_metric_spaces

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof of continuity iff inverse image of an open set is open](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3194973/proof-of-continuity-iff-inverse-image-of-an-open-set-is-open)

Comment: But if y is held a constant isn't it the normal definition of continuity? I forgot to mention that

Comment: I know it does, I am sorry and I corrected it, now can you help me?

Comment: Please look at Wikipedia and at the proposed duplicate, both linked above. (There are probably many other duplicates.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ou shloud not look at a fixed open set: $f$ is continuous if, for every open set $V$,$f^{-1}(V)$ is an open set. Thus, (for fixed $y)$, you look at the open set $V=B(f(y),\epsilon)$; as $f^{-1}(V)$ is open and as $y\in f^{-1}(V)$, there is a ball $B(y,\delta)$ contained in  $f^{-1}(V)$.

Of course, there may be points $x$ such that $d(x,y)\geq \delta$ and $x\in f^{-1}(V)$, but you are interested only in points in the ball $B(y,\delta)$.

Comment: This was a FAQ. Please do not edit answers to duplicates, or do it on the older question if you feel your answer adds something to the previous ones.